# Is there an If...Then loop for non existant HTML tag in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of names I want to google birthdays for. This VBA script allows me to search and pull data from Google only if it has the specific element with that class name.

```
Sub Searcher()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim y As Integer 
Dim x As Integer
Dim result As String 



Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

y = 2

For x = 2 To 3000

objIE.Visible = True

objIE.navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & y).Value & "+" & Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B" & y).Value & "+Born"


Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set doc = objIE.document

result = doc.getElementsByClassName("_XWk")(0).innerText

Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C" & y).Value = result


y = y + 1

Next

objIE.Quit

End Sub
```

If the site does not have an element with that class name, it times out and gives an error. I was wondering if there is some sort of If/Then I would be able to use if the site does not have that class name and have it skip to the next search. Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error must occur here and is probably a "424 Object, variable or with block not set" error.

```
result = doc.getElementsByClassName("_XWk")(0).innerText
```

And the reason is, because if `doc.getElementsByClassName("_XWk")` does not exist, then that *part* of the chained expression evaluates to `Nothing`. So you end up with:

```
result = Nothing(0).innerText
```

Which fails, because you can't index a `Nothing` and you can't `.innerText` an error :)

The solution is to avoid chaining expressions which might evaluate to `Nothing`, and handle errors appropriately:

```
If doc.getElementsByClassName("_XWk") Is Nothing Then
    'Do nothing
Else
    result = doc.getElementsByClassName("_XWk")(0).innerText
    Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C" & y).Value = result
End If
y = y + 1 '## might need to put this up in the Else block, I'm not sure.
```

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback. Much appreciated. I started running the script and it worked like a charm up to this point. David, this was the error I came across. Thanks for the heads up. I appreciate getting the understanding too.

Comment: CHeers @Chris do consider marking answer as "Accepted" if it's solved your problem :)

Comment: I tried it out, it makes sense that it would work but it did not. I even moved the y = y + 1 line into the else block

Comment: I take that back, i used your theory and added (0) on the end of the If element and now it works like a charm

Comment: @Chris ok that makes sense also. It's possible (I didn't test it, just shooting from memory) that the `doc.getElementsByClassName("_XWk")` returns something like an empty collection, not a `Nothing`. Good job figuring it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Set resultClasses = html.getElementsByTagName("div") 
For Each resultClass In resultClasses 
    If resultClass.getAttribute("class") = "_XWk" Then 
        Msgbox "Found"
        Exit For 
    End If 
Next resultClass
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that